# I want to run Turbo C++ in my 64bit laptop? But I can't find any version that support 64bit platforms

Tags: turbo-c++

I want to run Turbo C++ in my 64bit laptop? But I can't find any version of tc that support 64bit platforms.

Do you know of any place I can download a compatible version?

Comment: Why on earth do you want to run Turbo C?

Comment: I am teaching turbo c++ to some of my students, and I want to show them some code in my laptop

Comment: You are not doing your students any favours by teaching them using Turbo C++ - the version of the language it supports is extremely outdated. There are many better, free, alternatives.

Comment: I've seen more than one instance of people using Turbo C++ for teaching - and asking questions about it on SO.  I'm guessing that quite a few educational institutions have courses in this that they haven't updated in years.

Comment: Can you please refer me some of the alternatives

Comment: @Starx Google for "site:stackoverflow.com  C++ windows ide" for many questions on this.

Comment: @Starx Microsoft Visual Studio Express for Windows, any editor or ide (Kate, jEdit, Eclipse, kDevelop) for linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not off the top of my head, but you could run up a 32 bit VM and use that.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a DOS application, then you can run it in virtual machine or in [DosBOX](http://www.dosbox.com/). Although DosBOX made for running DOS games, it should handle Turbo C and it is easier to set up than full VM.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to run it in a virtual machine like [Bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/), which specialises in emulating the older stuff.

You can run [FreeDOS](http://www.freedos.org/) inside it so you're not bothered by licensing issues, although it will run MS DOS if you have a valid copy.

But I have to admit, I agree with your commenters. You'd be better off teaching your students with a more modern compiler. [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) springs to mind and Microsoft themselves release a free (as in cost, not freedom) Visual C package.